# Office Add-in are not showing on Outlook for IOS Add-in list

Tags: ios, outlook, outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-addins

We have an Outlook add that is approved for IOS. https://store.office.com/en-001/app.aspx?assetid=WA104380464 In most cases the add-in is showing in the Add-in list on Outlook for IOS.

[Add-in list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tie2T.png)

However, some tenant only shows the default add-ins. No other Add-ins that are deployed on the Exchange Online Add-in catalog that has IOS support are showing. We tried with different accounts and devices on these tenants. But nothing happens the add-in is not showing. My question is.

Is there a setting on Exchange Online or Office 365 that disable this? Or why is it showing on some tenant and other not?

Hope for a quick response, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For an add-in to be visible on Outlook Mobile it has to have mobile form factor and should be either side-loaded or be approved by outlook mobile.
iPlanner Pro has mobile form factor but is not approved for Outlook Mobile. This is the reason it is not visible until and unless side-loaded.

You can uninstall the addin from management screen in settings and reset the account and confirm if the addin still appears. If not, it was sideloaded by you. Another thing to add is that Installing an addin that is not approved like iPlanner Pro from store will not make it visible on mobile.

Answer (score -1):

Let me try to be more specific. iPlanner Pro, FedEx, eMail2SharePoint and several more of our Add-ins are all approved at the Office Store. NOT for IOS (yet) however, they do all have IOS support.

The add-in is working on outlook client on MAC and windows and is working using webmail. The only issue is on Outlook for IOS. Only the default add-ins are showing on the list. NON OTHER has been deployed correctly and 100% by the book.

The add-ins (all of the above) are functioning without any problems on all devices perfectly also on Outlook for IOS on many Office 365 tenants. Besides our own and a demo tenant we have, it is working on many customer tenants in different countries. See attached screenshot. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxRV1.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJfLt.png)

When we started receiving support requests from the customer where the add-ins are not visible on IOS, we started the different tests. Some customers did not have the issue and others did. We knew it was not the Add-in. We asked one of the customers where the add-in was not showing too.

1. try with other add-ins - Non were showing, only the default standard.
2. Connect to our demo tenant - The add-in was now showing and all worked.

this can only mean one thing. There is a problem with the tenant.

We run this test with two others with the same result.

Based on that the conclusion is simple. Some office 365 tenants simply do not show add-ins deployed from the exchange online catalog or directly from the store to a specific user.

These tenants must have a problem

Comment: iPlanner Pro, FedEx, eMail2SharePoint are not whitelisted on Outlook iOS. This means they are not expected to be visible on Outlook IOS. They can only be visible on outlook iOS by sideloading [sideloading an add-in and installing it from the store are completely different things]. The administrator can also sideload an add-in for the entire org.  Can you confirm if the add-in is sideloaded or not by referring to my 1st answer.

Comment: MoreOver You can go to Outlook Web->Settings->Manage Addins-> My Addins. With the list of Addins, there is a text saying if the add-in is installed by the administrator. Do check this and reply back.

Comment: I can confirm that we have tested in both ways. 1. sideloaded by the user 2. By and administrator from Exchange online catalog directly from the Store and activated properly. Again please notice, they are working on the client and web. 

I have implemented these add-in at least 50 different tenants and it has been done by many them self. It is wokring perfectly on IOS for most. BUT some tenant are not showing other than the std. 

And if the user is connecting to another tenant he can get the above add-in with no problem.

The problem is on some tenants - and NOT the add-ins.

Comment: These add-ins are not whitelisted for outlook-iOS, They will get visible on other outlook platforms if installed from the store but not on iOS until and unless whitelisted by us. I can guarantee that tenants showing these add-ins have it sideloaded either by the user or administrator. Check on tenants on which they are visible and confirm if they are sideloaded or not?

Comment: Hi Shubham. Are we going in circles :-)  YOU SAY  " I can guarantee that tenants showing these add-ins have it sideloaded either by the user or administrator"  I AM SAYING. This is exactly what I am saying. on some tenant add-ins that are sideloaded are not showing. I know that add-ins that are not whitelisted will not show among the default on IOS. I AM NOT TALKING ABOUT THIS. Side loaded add-ins or add-ins from the store installed by an administrator with IOS support are not showing on IOS.

Comment: We are looking into this